# Отловить момент звукового сигнала

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Есть ли возможность отловить момент воспроизведения определённого звука на компьютера?

Comment: .net подразумевает работу только под Виндой. .net-core - обычно подразумевает кроссплатформу. Соответственно, решения будут разными. Что нужно?

Comment: Детектировать просто проигрывание звука можно: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23829571/5045688. Но вот как быть с выявлением _определенного_...

Answer (score 0):

Если нам известен звук, значит нам известен и файл.

Предполагаю, что может сработать банальная проверка не читается ли файл со звуком в даный момент:

```
protected virtual bool IsFileLocked(FileInfo file)
{
    FileStream stream = null;

    try
    {
        stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
        //the file is unavailable because it is:
        //still being written to
        //or being processed by another thread
        //or does not exist (has already been processed)
        return true;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (stream != null)
            stream.Close();
    }

    //file is not locked
    return false;
}
```

Может и не сработает. Но лучше попробовать.

Код взят отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876473/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-file-is-in-use